# Почему дублируется каталог поиска исполняемых файлов

Tags: linux, администрирование

Я хочу добавить в путь поиска исполняемый файл из каталога */~/bin* Например, в файл *.bashrc* пишу вот так:

```
PATH=/home/lary/bin/pycharm-community-2019.1.2/bin:$PATH; export PATH
```

После перезагрузки вижу вот такую вещь:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/lary/bin/pycharm-community-2019.1.2/bin:/home/lary/bin/pycharm-community-2019.1.2/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

Почему путь добавляется дважды ?

В файл .bashrc, после изменения PATH добавил строку:

```
echo 'Add to PATH' >> ~/tmp/dbg.txt
```

После прелогина вижу в файле dbg.txt:

```
Add to PATH
Add to PATH
```

Comment: Видимо ваш bashrc исполняется дважды

Comment: @AlexeyTen Можно предположить, что первый раз - когда логинюсь в систему, а второй раз - когда открываю окно терминала (после входа). Но как тогда этого избежать ?

Comment: Ну надо смотреть что, как и когда исполняется. Вообще в стандартном графическом логине bashrc не должен выполнятся. Для начала можно написать рядом в этой командой какой-нибудь `echo debug` и посмотреть сколько раз появится сообщение при запуске терминала.

Comment: @AlexeyTen - "написать рядом в этой командой какой-нибудь echo "

Дописал в исходный вопрос.